# removing 'this' clicked list element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a todo list but am struggling to find a solution, using vanilla Javascript, to remove a list item once it has been clicked.

Appending the users input as list items was the straightforward part, but I have just realised that this particular part of the task is more challenging than what I first suspected.

This is my first ever JS project. With every list item that is appended, there is also a button element added on within that list item as a child.

The idea is, when the user clicks this button, it will remove that particular list item from the unordered list.

Any suggesstions here?

```js
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function() {

  var taskinput = document.getElementById("task").value;

  if (taskinput) {

    var tasktext = document.createTextNode(taskinput);
    var list = document.createElement("li");
    list.appendChild(tasktext);
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.setAttribute("id", "completed");
    button.innerHTML = "completed";
    list.appendChild(button);
    document.getElementById("task-to-do").appendChild(list);
    document.getElementById("task").value = "";
  } else {
    alert("Please enter a task");
  }

  document.getElementById("completed").addEventListener("click", function() {

  })

})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 2% 2% 2% 2%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #6363B6;
}

li button {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 1%;
  clear: both;
  float: right;
  background-color: #6363B6;
}
```

```html
<div id="incomplete-tasks">
  <h4>INCOMPLETE TASKS</h4>
  <ul id="task-to-do">

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are the elements with id's `add`, `task` and `completed`.

Comment: Really sorry, it was a copy + paste error. <input type="text" id="task"><img id="add" src="add.png"> and the completed tasks id is assigned to another <ul> list where the items will be moved to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of custom attribute to identify the Id of selected item from button. Data attributes will be useful in your case.

Follow the steps as follows:

1. When you are creating `li` element for a task. Assign an unique id attribute using counter e.g. id = 1, 2, 3, etc.

   ```
   var list = document.createElement("li");
   list.setAttribute('id', (value-of-last-li-id) + 1);
   ```
2. Similarly when creating `button` element give it a data attribute `data-id` with same id value of li and common `class` attribute value.

   ```
   var button = document.createElement("button");
   button.setAttribute('data-id', (value-of-last-li-id) + 1);
   button.setAttribute('class', 'delete-btn');
   ```
3. Add an event listener for `click` event on that button, that will fetch the `data-id` of the button and using that value you can remove that `li` element with same `data-id` value of button clicked.

   ```
   var delete_btns = document.getElementsByClassName('delete-btn');

   var delete_task = function() {
       var li_id = this.getAttribute('data-id');
       document.getElementById(li_id).remove();
   }

   for (var i = 0; i < delete_btns.length; i++) {
       delete_btns[i].addEventListener('click', delete_task);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Don't give the buttons ids. You will have duplicate ids. Instead add the event listener at the same time you create the button. That way you also get instant access to the li.

```
... 
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    list.parentNode.removeChild(list);
});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you how to `remove` the clicked element.

```js
var listItem = document.querySelectorAll('li');

console.log(listItem)

listItem.forEach(function($li){
 $li.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if($li.classList.contains('completed')) {
       $li.remove()
      }
  })
})
```

```css
ul{
  list-style: none;
}
ul>li{
  background: #d2d2d2;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul>li.completed{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Task 1</li>
  <li>Task 2</li>
  <li class="completed">Task 3</li>
  <li>Task 4</li>
  <li class="completed">Task 5</li>
</ul>
```